# glass diode marking has two bands not mentioned in datasheets

Tags: diodes, identification

I found a diode in my pack of unsoldered diodes, but can not identify it.

Could you please help to identify the diode? I searched Vishay datasheets and some others and nowhere is mentioned diode with second brown band.

The only I found is here ([marsport](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/sod80.htm)) where in the table for MELF/SOD-80 it is defined to be LL4148 or LL914 diodes. but there is no mention for brown band in datasheets and only on the marsport site's table it is mentioned.

Here is the picture
[image: The diode with two bands]

Comment: Any chance you could measure the forward voltage drop, and through a high-value resistor, the avalanche voltage?  Such numbers could help clarify which one it could be.

Comment: @rdtsc when I set multimeter to diode checking it shows 0.561V. Resistance is 0.855 M Ohm. But I am not sure yet if I could do an avalanche voltage test.

Comment: @rdtsc Capacitance is always different from 0.08 nF to 13 nF and finally OL.